# CSS right prop not working when position: sticky

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky

I am trying to align a sticky button to the right, but the right CSS property not working only the left is

Please let me know why, and How can I solve?

Example Below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="padding: 20px;">
    <div style="background-color: whitesmoke; width: 400px; position: relative; max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- bottom: 20px; left: 20px; working! -->
        <button style="position: sticky; bottom: 20px; left: 20px;">btn</button>
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: whitesmoke; width: 400px; position: relative; max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- right: 20px; Not working  (bottom: 20px; always working) -->
        <button style="position: sticky; bottom: 20px; right: 20px;">btn</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I solved,

If you use right prop with sticky position, use float: right together

Comment: Is the use of `float: right` still relevant in 2023? Can this be done better... For example, using `display: flex` and formatting the child elements as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working but you could use `left: 100%;` as a workaround to get the intended result

Like this:

```html
<div style="padding: 20px;">
    <div style="background-color: whitesmoke; width: 400px; position: relative; max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- bottom: 20px; left: 20px; working! -->
        <button style="position: sticky; bottom: 20px; left: 20px;">btn</button>
    </div>

    <div style="background-color: whitesmoke; width: 400px; position: relative; max-height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
        <ul>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
            <li style="margin-bottom: 60px;">1</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- right: 20px; Not working  (bottom: 20px; always working) -->
        <button style="position: sticky; bottom: 20px; left: 100%;">btn</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not position the `button`. Create an element, for example, named `footer`, and position it at the bottom so that multiple child elements, including the `button`, can be placed in the fixed bottom bar. It is easy to align the elements within the box, and the best approach is to use [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), where child elements can be positioned in numerous ways. I would highlight one approach:

- [`flex-direction: row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) (it will list the elements from left to right)
- [`flex-direction: row-reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) (it will list the elements from right to left)

See the example below:

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box > ul > li {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.box > .box-footer {
  /* Position fixed bottom */
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  /* Position child elements */
  display: flex;
}

.box > .box-footer.right {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<!-- Button on Left side -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="box-footer">
            <button>btn</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Button on Right side -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>1</li>
        </ul>
        
        <div class="box-footer right">
            <button>btn</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, following my example, I moved your `<style>` tags into CSS classes, allowing you to achieve the same result with less code. Then, I placed your `<button>` element as a child within a `<div>`. The `<div>` is aligned at the bottom using the `.box-footer` class with a sticky position. The `<div>` itself remains 100% wide and receives some padding.

For this `<div>` with the `.box-footer` class, I specified that its children should be displayed with `flex` styles. This allows me to use all the CSS properties associated with `flex`.

By default, if you need to align the button to the left, you wouldn't need this, but it doesn't hurt to have it.

If you want to align the element to the right, there are several ways to do it. Perhaps the simplest is to tell `flex` to list the items in reverse order using `flex-direction` (which I placed in a separate class, `.right`, so that I can demonstrate both the left and right examples with the `.box-footer`).